# How show user selection without generating all possible combinations with Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

My problem is quite simple : user selects 3 cars from a 2500 items list, then click to compare them on a detailed page.

In **gatsby-node.js**, I've generated 2500 details pages, one for each car:

```
    const { data: models } = await graphql(`query { myMongodbModels{ <my query here>}`);
    models['myMongodbModels'].edges.forEach(({ node: model }) => {
      actions.createPage({
        path: `/cars/${model.name}`,
        ...
      })
    });
```

I can display each car from its URL `/cars/{model}`

I was planning to access comparison page with URL like `/compare/{model1}-{model2}-{model3}`

But I can't generate all 3 out of 2500 combinations, that would be a lot!

I can't figure out to do it **without querying the database at runtime**, because it would not be static Gatsby site anymore...

Please tell me if there is another way to do this, or if my use case is out of Gatsby scope

Comment: That would be silly if you would create page for each possible combination of 3 cars. YOu would probably need to access the database at runtime as you mentioned. Make a fetch request to DB and you will be good to go....Why exactly you don't want to do it like that? 

Gatsby is built on top of the react app.

Comment: yes but in this case gatsby is totally useless for my purpose...ideally I hoped that gatsby would save me from having to host/maintain a live db just for this

Comment: Well Gatsby might not be totally useless. If you need to generate those 2500 product pages either way, especially with information that doesn't update very often, having static pages as a base could be a boost for performance. From within those pages you can still pull dynamic data from any api and have a comparison component that loads data after the initial page load.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why gatsby was made :)

Comment: ok, I agree, but is there any way to include this static content into another one? I mean a cleaner solution than good old iframes, like injecting DOM elements or something like this?

Comment: I suppose my last question is unrelated to this subject, thanks for your answers mkEagles and ksav

Comment: I'm planning to fetch static pages and inject content using dangerouslySetInnerHTML